# Why does this SELECT query disconnect from SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

This query:

select '%3c%73%63%72%69%70%74'

Disconnects a TCP/IP connection to SQL Server. The string is a URL encoding of `<script`. I can imagine that there may be defence mechanisms that look for `<script` and take counter-measures -- what is it in this can that is closing the connection?

Comment: Works fine for me, causes no disconnect and outputs the string perfectly. Perhaps its a specific version?

Comment: Can you run the query on the server itself instead of connecting remotely? We don't know what your security set up is

Comment: Do you have connection pooling off?

Comment: Which version of SQL Server? It is not disconnecting for me..

Comment: If you run the query on the server it runs okay. I have tried it with 2012 and 2014. I am running it from SSMS

Comment: You could check the connection logs for clues. Maybe run a trace. My guess is that the connection is being closed by a client or middleware and not by the server

Comment: Hmm, interesting. SQL Server shows nothing which would maybe suggest it happens in the middle somewhere.

Comment: Perhaps a firewall in between you and the server is doing deep packet inspection and detecting what it thinks may be script injection?

Comment: If this is being sent over an HTTP socket with a Windows box receiving the content, it's IIS that's catching you - it's a dangerous string, as far as IIS is concerned.

Comment: It was the firewall thinking it was an injection attempt. Thanks guys. If one of you wants to put up an answer I'll mark it as correct.